# es6 js element best practice

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm trying to set the width and height of an element with JavaScript to cover the entire browser viewport, and I'm successful using `document.body.clientHeight`
but in IE6, it seems that I always get horizontal and vertical scrollbars because the element must be slightly too big.
Now, I really don't want to use browser specific logic and substract a pixel or 2 from each dimension just for IE6. Also, I am not using CSS (width: 100% etc.) for this because I need the pixel amounts.

Does anyone know a better way to fill the viewport with an element in IE6+ (obviously all good browsers, too)?

Edit: Thanks Owen for the suggestion, I'm sure jQuery will work. I should have specified that I need a toolkit-agnostic solution.

The best implementation.

Comment: The way the DOM works has nothing to do with JavaScript versions.

Comment: Also, who on earth is using IE6?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on a site, using jQuery solves the issue!

```
var width = $(document).width();
var height = $(document.height();

$('#mySpecialElement').width(width).height(height);
```